# How to merge (using DataFrame) two data sets with the same inputs but in a different order

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two datasets where one can be essentially thought of as a descriptor set and the other contains the information.

I have a simple example of what I mean here.

```
import pandas as pd
```

The first dataset, i.e. descriptor:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"color": ["blue", "yellow", "red"],
                    "abbv": ["b", "y", "r"]})
```

The second dataset:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"color_1": ["blue", "red", "yellow"],
                    "color_2": ["yellow", "blue", "red"],
                    "total": ["green", "purple", "orange"]})
```

What I am trying to do is use pd.merge in order to merge the two datasets such that the final dataset would look like this:

```
 | color_1 | color_2 | total | abbv_1 | abbv_2 |
 | ------- | ------- | ----- | ------ | ------ |
 |  blue   |  yellow | green |   b    |   y    |
      .          .       .       .        .
      .          .       .       .        .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mapping Series can be created from `df1` with [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html). Then the new columns can be added to `df2` with [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
# Create the Mapping Series
mapper = df1.set_index('color')['abbv']
# Add the New Columns
df2['abbv_1'] = df2['color_1'].map(mapper)
df2['abbv_2'] = df2['color_2'].map(mapper)
```

Or iteratively over all color columns by filtering columns with [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
mapper = df1.set_index('color')['abbv']
for c in df2.columns[df2.columns.str.contains('color')]:
    df2[f'abbv_{c.rsplit("_", 1)[-1]}'] = df2[c].map(mapper)
```

`df2`:

```
  color_1 color_2   total abbv_1 abbv_2
0    blue  yellow   green      b      y
1     red    blue  purple      r      b
2  yellow     red  orange      y      r
```